# Resources on basics of 3D model rendering

Tags: opengl, model, rendering, textures, mesh

Maybe I've missed something, but I couldn't find any questions about this already. If anyone knows of any then it would be great if you could post the links.

I know there's loads of massive opensource engines out there already that it'd be really easy to use, it's not a problem of needing one, but I don't like not knowing how the things I want to use work. But looking around, I can't find anything on it. I'm not some masochistic nutjob on a crazy lone mission to make an engine.

I've done all the basics of OpenGL already, I can hardcode it to draw something, I don't need a complete runthrough from first starting it, but I haven't a clue how to move that on to rendering a model, and nothing anywhere seems to explain it. I've tried to see if I can find anything on the structure of any file types to see if I could figure out myself how you use them to render the model, but that was a bit of a dead end.

Comment: I took a course on graphics programming at one point. The textbook spent most of it's time on 3D rendering: say 1000 of the 1200 pages. It's a big subject, with lots of different incompatible or only partially compatible approaches that all have different strengths and weakness. On top of which advances in hardware capacity and design *change* the trade offs every few years. Taken together this means that it may be hard to find anything like a unified resource on the subject.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't expecting a single resource on it, I understand that it's a massive area, but I can't even find things covering small areas of it, for any point, let alone the recent state of everything.
If nothing else comes up though, could I ask what the book was, if you found it helpful?

Comment: Small apartment, so my whole technical library is at the office right now. I'll try to remember to get the title on Monday... I liked it because it covered a lot of stuff and included some history showing when various techniques were used in what fields, and why. On top of which the professor had been doing real-time graphics for about 30 years (starting when updating a few, simple wire frames at 10 Hz was hot stuff).

Comment: [Computer Graphics Principles and Practice](http://www.amazon.com/Computer-Graphics-Principles-Practice-2nd/dp/0201848406) by Foley, van Dam, Feiner and Hughes. We used the second edition.

Comment: Ah cool, my uni library has it, saves me 70 quid :D
Be going and picking that up tomorrow definitely, sounds perfect for what I want, thanks a lot DMC!

Answer (score 0):

[Section 24](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/miscellaneous.htm) of the OpenGL FAQ has some topics covering loading/rendering of various file formats. Specifically section 24.040.

One of the more common formats that is used with OpenGL is the [obj file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obj), probably because many programs can export to it. There's plenty of resources around regarding obj to Google up.